# boost unique_lock created on the heap instead of stack causes crash on mingw

Tags: boost, locking, unique

does anyone know why boost unique lock objects can only be instantiated on the stack and not on the heap?

This works perfectly:

```
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> lock1(mutex1);
:
wait_condition.wait(lock1);
```

But this causes a runtime crash on both Windows 7 & Windows 8 after compiling with mingw:

```
boost::unique_lock *lock1;
lock1 = new boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>(mutex1);
:
wait_condition.wait(*lock1);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't mention neither what version of boost you're talking of, nor where and how it crashes. But just out of curiosity: what's the point to create a special RAII facility on the heap? You could just lock/unlock the mutex manually...

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks Igor for your response. I'm using boost 1.52.0. The RAII statement made me think and then I realised what I should have realised before: Creating it on the heap means the lock never goes out of scope even after exiting the function where the unique_lock is created. When wait returns, it re-locks, without unlocking the heap-based lock when the function returns, causing deadlock. By crash in this context I meant "application freezing and not letting me close it".

The above problem is solved. However, I now have a new problem :-)  After following the RAII paradigm and using the stack, my application still crashes once I have 25 child threads in a wait-state. I don't know why. Is there some Windows, boost or mingw limitation with over 25 threads waiting on a mutex? The over-25-thread crash is worse than above; it crashes properly with a Windows error: "The application was forced to close in an unexpected way". This doesn't happen with less than 25 threads...

Comment: 1) It's worth creating another question and providing some code -- at least, the lines where it crashes. 2) "The application was forced to close in an unexpected way" message doesn't help much; run your application in the debugger, and see what exception do you observe. 3) No, there's no limitation of 25 threads.